# <head> tag pops out to <body> tag

Tags: html, css, web

Something weird is happened to me when i write this code in  tag in html:

```
<div id="header1" style="background-color:white;color:grey;font-size:20px;">
    <img id="MainImg" src="StatMarketlogo_final.gif" style="float:left;">
    <b>Hello Amit,you last login was on 5/3/2015</b>
</div>
```

It pop's out from `<head>` tag and go to `<body>` tag.
What happened?
I am doing this because i want my background of head will be different from body back-color. So i want they will be in different tags.

Comment: Doed this also happen with the *id="header1"* removed? You may have styles associated to that ID.

Comment: img tag is self closing.  FYI

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't mean `<head>`...if you do then you can't put those elements in that section of the web page. Also, as mentioned, images are self-closing and the `font` tag has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes' it's still happened.

Comment: If i isolate the img tag in head. it will pop out in body tag. with or without closing.

Comment: "pop out"? can you add your code to a jsfiddle to replicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HEAD tag is not what you think it is. It contains information about the document: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp

Try changing your div to a header tag then style that separately to the rest of the document. Both of these should remain inside of the body tag:

```
 <header id="header1" style="background-color:white;color:grey;font-size:20px;">
     <img id="MainImg" src="StatMarketlogo_final.gif" style="float:left;">
     <b>Hello Amit,you last login was on 5/3/2015</b>
 </header>

 <div class="some-content" style="background-color:red;">
   Some content
 </div>
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the HEADER tag is an HTML5 element so you need to make sure your doctype is correct: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp

Answer (score 3):

The end tag for the head element is optional.

The start tag for the body element is optional.

A div element is not allowed inside the head element. (Div elements include content, the head element isn't supposed to hold any content, only meta data like the `<title>` and `<link>`s to stylesheets.).

Putting a div start tag before you have a head end tag will implicitly end the head element and start the body element.

---

It sounds like your `<div>` should actually be a `<header>` that is **inside** the `<body>` and before your `<main>`.